# Программирование компьютерной графики

Tags: opengl, графика, directx

Всем привет.Я работаю программистом в области web.
Имею хорошую базу в виде C++.
Уже давно мучает желания сменить направление на gamedev.
А именно хотелось бы попробовать себя в роли программиста компьютерной графики.

Может кто посоветовать с чего начать? Интересуют самые азы.То есть,может есть хорошая книга по графике ? Я имею ввиду не конкретная спецификация (вроде opengl or directx) а именно необходимая база.

Буду весьма благодарен.Спасибо

Comment: Читали про движки типа Unity?

Comment: а ведь нормальный вопрос человек задал! Такое чувство что новичкам в определенных областях, когда человек не знает куда податься просто закрывают рот. А для чего тогда нужен Stack Overlow? Разве не для помощи друг другу?! Что за дискриманция!